# Table of content only on right-side pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

Is there any way I can force all the pages of table of contents (and its family) to be printed only on the right side ?

Presently I am having it as :

```
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}}
\listofalgorithms
\cleardoublepage
```

My table of content is a long one and it spans over 2 pages. But they are printed as back-to-back. Is it possible that I can print them only on the right hand side pages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of two pages, package `\afterpage` helps in putting `\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}` right at the begin of the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% for testing only
\usepackage{afterpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage\protect\cleardoublepage}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
\chapter{C}
\section{D}
\chapter{E}
\section{F}
\chapter{G}
\section{H}
\chapter{I}
\section{J}
\chapter{K}
\section{L}
\chapter{M}
\section{N}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried this. Still no change.

Comment: @gaganbm: The chapter header of the table of contents had interfered. Now the updated answer puts the `\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}` at the begin of the `.toc` file.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want blank even pages not just in the table of contents, but everywhere in the front matter.  Package `everyshi` allows you to add "every shipout" code that can check whether the page is even and if yes, output a blank page.  The counter `\c@page` can be used for this.  You also need to switch off this feature inside main matter.

This code seems to work:

```
\usepackage{everyshi}
\makeatletter
\EveryShipout{\if@mainmatter\else\ifodd\c@page\null\pagebreak\fi\fi}
\makeathother
```

Comment: Very informative. Yes, I was looking for printing the front matter only on odd pages. Fore the rest of the pages, like abstract etc., it was easily done with '\cleardoublepage'. Anyways, I already used the other approach, but will take note of this one for future.

Answer (score 1):

You can add commands to the TOC using `\addtocontents{toc}{\whatever}`. If your documentclass is book, memoir, scrbook, or another book-like class `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cleardoublepage}` should do what you want. Just insert it after the last chapter that you want to appear on page ix. I am not sure whether `\protect` is necessary.