# How do I put a blank page between two pages of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, blank-page

My table of contents have two pages, page ix and page x, but I want to just let even pages have contents, so I have to put a blank page between those two. So I need to have the TOC at pages ix and xi, but page x completely blank. Somebody knows how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Table of content only on right-side pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118170) Please, have a look at the linked question and tell if it helps; otherwise, add to your question what doesn't work, with a simple example.