# Table of contents only on right-hand side pages

Tags: table-of-contents, double-sided

I need to have a table of contents only on right-hand sided (even) pages, a goal similar to what was described here: [Table of content only on right-side pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118170/table-of-content-only-on-right-side-pages). However, I have a table of contents spanning at least 3 pages, and while

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage\protect\cleardoublepage}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

does add one blank page after the first toc page, the following pages appear as well in the left side.

Is there a way to have all pages of this kind of front matter (particularly the TOC) only right-sided while using the report document class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution in viable time, so I ended up by manually editing the `doc.toc` table of contents index and adding several `\afterpage \cleardoublepage` commands through it to force clearing the pages.

In the main document I replaced the `\tableofcontents` command with `\input doc.toc` which prevents indexing a new table of contents and reads the file I've manually edited:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\input doc.toc
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

If anyone still has a programmatic solution, please contribute.

**EDIT**:
Instead of manually editing the .toc file one can add a

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage\protect\cleardoublepage}
```

command throughout the main text (e.g. after the begining of each chapter), which will add the `\cleardoublepage` command to the .toc just the same. This way, you can call the toc with `\tableofcontents` as always.