# Table of content only on right-side pages for many entrys

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

I want my front matter to be only on odd pages. This should include the toc. I have seen a solution to this before ([Table of content only on right-side pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118170/table-of-content-only-on-right-side-pages)) but this does not work if your contents page consists of more than 2 pages. Here is an example of how badly it fails....

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=2cm, inner=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage\protect\cleardoublepage}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}\section{1}


\end{document}
```

Is there any way to fix this and have the table of contents behave as I would like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use paracol to put one column each on two pages.  Without the savebox, the table of contents doesn't show up until page 6.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=2cm, inner=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{\let\cleardoublepage=\relax
  \tableofcontents}%
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\section{1}
You need at least one line of text.
\switchcolumn
\unvbox\tempbox
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```